# Remove last "/" from string in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have a string like:

**http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/1dZEOLADapg/**

I want to use this string to load html page. But because of "/" at last in string, I get the URL is as null.

my code is as follow:

```
NSURL *ur=[NSURL URLWithString:Mystring];
        NSLog(@"%@",ur); //getting null value

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:ur];

        NSLog(@"%@",requestObj);
```

So, **How can i remove this last "/" from string??**

Comment: I really doubt that you can't convert a NSString to a NSURL just because there's a `/` on the end.

Comment: Can you add another NSLog to see what the value of `Mystring` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code ...

```
    NSString *Mystring = @"http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/1dZEOLADapg/";
    if ([Mystring isEqualToString:@""]||[Mystring isEqual:nil]) {

        NSLog(@"\n\n String is NULL");
    }
    else {
        NSString *TempURl = [Mystring substringToIndex:[Mystring length]-1];

        NSString *urlstr =[TempURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        urlstr =[urlstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

        urlstr =[urlstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
        [urlstr retain];

        NSURL *ur=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
        NSLog(@"%@",ur); //now get string value here

        //        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:ur];
        //        
        //        NSLog(@"%@",requestObj);
    }
```

I Got Log OutPut : **http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/1dZEOLADapg**

hope this help you...

Comment: sorry, but i get the same string with "/".

Comment: @user1673099 now just copy this code and paste in your viewWillAppear: method and see the log...after post comment dude.. :)

Comment: yes,you are right. But when try with passing dynamically , i am getting the the same string with "/".

Comment: what you get in dyanmic value??? just post that string which got from it and log also

Comment: sorrrrrryyyy...., yes your code is working but the problem is when i try to print string in Log it shows me same as i ask in question. But when i put mouse on string variable it shows me like http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/ZCwsR8o3KM8/\n\t\t  so,when i try your code the last \t removed but i always show in log like http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/ZCwsR8o3KM8/

Comment: oh dude so here problem with this , here we romove the last character of string so this last character \t remove .. wait i go something to overcome this problem..

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure it's because of the last `'/'`? Could it be because of the `'~'` character in the middle?

Whichever way, to check for the last character, simply do

```
unichar last = [urlString characterAtIndex:urlString.length - 1];
if (last == '/')
    urlString = [urlString substringToIndex:urlString.length - 1];
```

Comment: yes, i am sure it's because of '/'.  I also try your code but the condition is not satisfy.

Comment: Am I missing something or would this not crash on empty strings (length = 0)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to encode the string like:

```
NSString *encodedString = [Mystring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: i am getting the same string after this coding.

Comment: After encoding it, it should be safe to use it

Comment: Roland has probably the right answer :) BTW for last character check simply use [string hasSuffix:@"/"] :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you need to remove the last character from string in every case, then you can get a newString as

```
NSString *newString = [oldString substringToIndex:[oldString length]-1];
```

Comment: if oldString is empty this would crash

Comment: @RolandKeesom it can be fixed easily with the condition `if ([oldString length] > 0) { NSString *newString = [oldString substringToIndex:[oldString length]-1]; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you

```
NSString * Mystring=@"http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/MakePartsFast/~3/1dZEOLADapg/";
[alfa substringToIndex:alfa.length-1];
```